# Escaping quotes in bash

Tags: string, macos, bash, unix

I am passing a filename to `scp` as argument, to write a file with a specific name.

This is part of an alias in .bash_profile, so i'm trying to automate the inclusion of the current date in the name of the file that gets written.

At the moment, I have this:

```
alias getlog='scp admin@censored.co.za:public/censored/current/log/exceptions.log "exceptions_$(date +\"%d_%b_%Y\").log"'
```

Let's focus on the second argument of the `scp` command. It writes the filename in this format:

> exceptions_"20_Jan_2015".log

Firstly, the quotes are included in the name, which I don't want. And I also prefer spaces in the name rather than underscores, so that it looks like this:

> exceptions 20 Jan 2015.log

What do I need to know about strings and escaping in bash to do this?

Comment: If you didn't want the quotes in the filename, why did you include them in the `date` format? One thing you need to know about escaping is that an escaped quote is just another character. And if you want to replace the underscores with spaces, just do that, but either backslash-escape the spaces (so that they are just another character) or quote the format with unescaped quotes (so that they are really quotes).

Comment: For a good in-depth discussion of shell quoting, I'd suggest http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes -- it's a lot of content, but then, it's a big and important topic.

Comment: ...passing content through ssh or scp is actually trickier, quoting-wise, than the general case -- there's security impact if anything that's intended to be treated data can be interpreted by code by the remote shell performing expansions (in the scp case) or running a command given as an argument (in the ssh case). For that reason, a comprehensive answer to this question is more complex than it would to just fix your immediate problem without keeping in mind that you're generating data to be used with scp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the escapes on the double-quotes in the date command's arguments - they make the shell treat the double-quotes as part of the format string (which means they eventually wind up in the filename) rather than delimiters *around* the format string (which is what you want). Now that you have a properly double-quoted format string, just replace the underscores with spaces. Compare the before & after output of the date command:

```
$ date +\"%d_%b_%Y\"
"20_Jan_2015"
$ date +"%d %b %Y"
20 Jan 2015
```

Here's the final alias:

```
alias getlog='scp admin@censored.co.za:public/censored/current/log/exceptions.log "exceptions_$(date +"%d %b %Y").log"'
```

Note that the double-quotes around `"exceptions_ ... .log"` are needed to keep the shell from word-splitting on the spaces in the date string.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fighting with quotes and nested quotes it is much cleaner to use a BASH function instead of of an `alias`:

```
getlog() {
   scp admin@censored.co.za:public/censored/current/log/exceptions.log \
      exceptions_$(date '+%d_%b_%Y').log
}
```

Comment: This is true and correct. It's also not a completely general answer -- works great for what `date` is emitting, but in cases with more interesting variable substitutions going on, `printf %q` and more cautious quoting can be called for.

Comment: Egg on my face here -- didn't take a close enough look and realize that only the _local_ file is being parameterized, so no remote unquoting layer involved. *facepalm*.

Comment: This is a good *solution*, but it does not answer my question. Thanks anyway